# Execute Javascript Advertise Script within AngularJS partial

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a webapplication where I need to place some Advertise-Scripts in some of my partials. The scripts are like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js">
    googletag.pubads().definePassback('/XYZ/TEST_allAdformats', [300, 250]).display();
</script>
```

The problem is, that currently the script isnt executed. As soon as I move it to index.html, everything works as expected. But that won't solve my problem, because I need to place it at a specific position within my partial.

Any help is appreciated.

Greets, Marc

Comment: Your partials are in the same folder that index.html ? Because you use a path in your javascript line.

Comment: No, they are in another folder which is controlled through routes. But that souldnt matter if I load an external JS file?

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in which I tried to execute a JS file at the end of partial view.
I loaded the $viewContentLoaded into the controller for the partial (or the directive). All you need in the $scope object in your controller declaration for injection. 
This seemed to fix it, but it may be a little bit harder as you have to load the script contents into the html.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(){
    //Do Something Here to load your script and insert it.
});
```

Hope this helps,

Patrick

Comment: Hi Maxiumus
Thanks for your help.
I tried your approach but the Advertise is not working like that. Any other suggestions?